# Cut, concatenate, and re-encode to h265 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two h264 videos that I would like to cut (each), concatenate and re-code into h265 - all with ffmpeg. How can I achieve that, considering that the following two approaches do not work?

### First approach

I tried

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05.500 -to 00:12:06.200 -i video1.mp4 \
       -ss 00:00:10.700 -to 01:43:47.000 -i video2.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [outv] [outa]" \
       -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" \
       -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy \
       final.mp4
```

but get the error message

> Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:1, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

### Second approach

Alternatively, I created the file `cutpoints.txt` with the content

```
file video1.mp4
inpoint 5.5
outpoint 726.2
file video2.mp4
inpoint 600.7
outpoint 6227.0
```

and ran the command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i cutpoints.txt -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy final.mp4
```

but then the video does not start exactly at 5.5 seconds, which is not surprising [since](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1)

> inpoint timestamp
>
> This directive works best with intra frame codecs, because for non-intra frame ones you will usually get extra packets before the actual In point and the decoded content will most likely contain frames before In point too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first approach and re-encode audio too:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05.500 -to 00:12:06.200 -i video1.mp4 \
       -ss 00:00:10.700 -to 01:43:47.000 -i video2.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [outv] [outa]" \
       -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" \
       -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 \
       final.mp4
```

Above uses the default audio codec; add non-copy `-c:a` as needed.